# Наскільки нормативним є вживання літери "И" на початку слова?

Tags: правопис, orthography, історія-мови

Я зауважив, що редактор [журналу "Ї"](http://www.ji.lviv.ua/) [Тарас Возняк](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BA_%D0%A2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81_%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) всюди використовує `и` на початку слова *инший* замість *інший* та, можливо других слів, які я не можу наразі зауважити, які [згідно літературної](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#par3) норми  мусять починаються із літери `і`:

> Коли **иншим** разом від улюбленого пивного кухля цісаря відбилося вухо, та ж фірма отримала замовлення зліпити усе знову докупи.
>
> ...
>
> Натомість при оплаті  рахунків цісаревої і **инших** родичів архикняжого дому цісар був великодушним і щедрим, як, зрештою, і пізніше, коли рятував катастрофічну фінансову  ситуацію родини Кісс-Шратт.
>
> ...

[Стаття у вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98) присвячена літері `И` подає список слів які починаються з неї згідно чинного правопису (серед яких немає *инший*), а також зауважує, що:

> На початку слів літера и в українській мові майже ніколи не пишеться. ...  [Проект правопису 1999](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%83_1999_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83), серед іншого, пропонує вживати «и» на початку не тільки запозичених власних назв, але й українських питомих та засвоєних слів перед приголосними «н» та «р», на початку відповідних вигуків, звуконаслідувань і похідних від них утворень (икати, инакший, иний). Прихильники проекту звертають увагу на наявність у живому мовленні слів із початковим «и», а також на приклади вживання її у зазначених випадках класиками української літератури до реформи правопису 1927 р.

Чи не потрафляли вам часом приклади вживання літери `и` напочатку слова *класиками української літератури до реформи правопису 1927 р.*, академічні дослідження, експертні думки чи бодай спроби наукового методу на цю тему?

Comment: «Записки кирпатого Мефістофеля» — роман Володимира Винниченка, 1916 р. та в інших творах трапляються використання слова, наприклад, `инший`. [корпус](http://www.mova.info/corpus.aspx) допомагає знайти.

Comment: Про питомість цієї норми можна судити з того, що вимова "инший" досі нормативна й не знищена, незважаючи на те, що вісімдесят років так заборонено писати.

Comment: «Иньші, що жертвували навіть більші суми на театр, заявляли, що робили се против переконання, тому бо так обставини складали ся, вітверто сказавши — не в станї були оперти ся пресії проводирів і преси.» («Літературно-науковий вісник», 1905, випуск 1–3.)

Answer (score 10):

У «Словнику української мови» Бориса Грінченка маємо до сотні слів з початковим `и` (щоправда, разом із похідними). Сучасні словники не фіксують жодного слова з початковим `и`, хоча реально вони вживаються в мові (дієслово `икати`, вигук `ич`, роман В. Дрозда (1939—2003) має назву «Ирій».

У Тараса Шевченка:

> "Гуси, гуси білі в ирій полетіли", "Посип индикам, гусям дай".

Примітка: я не зміг знайти посилання на твори Шевченка, де вживаються слова *ирій* та *индикам* (окрім Грінченка) - в усіх текстах вживаються сучасні варіанти *ірій* та *індикам*.

У 50-томному виданні Івана Франка у «Зів’ялому листі» читаємо:

> Зелений явір, зелений явір, ще зеленіша ива, ой, між усіма
>   дівчатоньками лиш одна мені мила.

Загадка (дзвін):

> В однім селі рубають, а в другім иверні літають.

Більш детально про слова та їх використання можна подивитись на [цій сторінці](http://hrinchenko.com/spisok/bukva/y-1.html).

Comment: `ива` лише як `верба`. І в українській літературі не зустрічав `иви`.

Comment: `индикам` - а цей варіант у нас існує насправді.

Comment: @BohdanKuts, в селах можна почути ще "гиндикам", думаю, що через складність вимови "и" на початку слова. Чи є інше пояснення?

Comment: [Посилання](https://archive.org/details/kobzarshcv00shevuoft) на «Гуси, гуси білі в ирій полетіли», там сторінка 285, внизу сторінки курсивом, це поема Шевченка «Марина», книга «Кобзарь. Повне народнє видання», Катеринослав — Кам’янець — Ляйпціґ, 1921.

Answer (score 7):

Грінченко цитує цілу купу слів. Приведу декілька для прикладу, що вживалось перед багатьма приголосними, не тільки `н`, або `р`:

*ива*, *идол*, *ижиця*, *икати*, *имберь*, *инаково*, *иньший* (зверніть увагу на наявність м'якого знаку; Грінченко не згадує, а у Грушевського є), *иржа*, *искра*, та багато інших.

Comment: Хтось може пояснити, чому таке відчуття неначе це все російські слова в оригінальній формі? Мені вони українськими чомусь не сприймаються.

Comment: @BohdanKuts, насправді, навпаки: вимова була різною у різних землях, та ще й змінювалася з часом, а церковнослов'янський правопис відставав.

Comment: @BohdanKuts в українській на початку 19-го століття все ще існувало аж 4 способи записувати, умовно кажучи, "і": (від найм'якшого до найтвердішого) `ї` (на той час писалось `Ѣ`), `і`, `и`, `ы`.

Answer (score 6):

Щодо нормативності, гадаю, що ви зрозуміли, що слова на кшталт "инший", не є нормативними, не потрібно на іспитах або під час ЗНО перевіряти їх нормативнисть. Даю декілька посилань на класиків:

П. Куліш, "[Чорна рада](https://books.google.ru/books?id=aSE1AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA67&dq=%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9&hl=uk&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwig7OnjsMHSAhUI2SwKHUgMBK4Q6AEIKjAE#v=onepage&q=%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9&f=false)", 1857.
[image: чорна рада]

---

Т. [Шевченко](https://books.google.ru/books?id=Y0FdAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA134&dq=%D0%98%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4&hl=uk&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiMo4fctcHSAhVsDZoKHfaRB4MQ6AEIJzAD#v=onepage&q=%D0%98%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4&f=false), 1867

[image: Шевченко]

---

[Байки](https://books.google.ru/books?id=CkFdAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA29&dq=%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BA&hl=uk&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiLo7zGt8HSAhUFOpoKHS_tCksQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BA&f=false), дарунок малим дітям, 1864

[image]

Але ще раз нагадаю, що в 19 сторіччі були різні способи записувати i, и та ї.