# Дивини абетки, правопису, фонетики та ортоґрафії

Tags: історія-мови, фонетика, правопис

Спільне:
— [Навіщо потрібен апостроф перед «ї»?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/53)

> … як і колишнє написання в російській твердого знака на кінці слів після приголосних, які й так були твердими, та ще й після питомо мʼяких *ч* та *щ* …

— [Наскільки нормативним є вживання літери "И" на початку слова?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/397)
— [Правила вживання літери г/ґ/х при запозиченні іншомовних слів на g/h (гакер, гостинг)](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/347)

На цьому розбіжності фонетики і правопису не закінчуються.

Спочатку я писав додаткову відповідь до першого запитання: наскільки можна вважати правопис раціональним у випадку апострофу. Але вирішив, що буде непогано створити окреме запитання задля збірок подібного. Я певен, що такого вистачає тут, особливо у випадку иншомовних слів.

---

Зміст

1. [Абетка](/a/4672/585)
2. [Апостроф](/a/2628/585)
3. [Иншомовні слова](/a/2629/585)

Comment: Я приблизно розумію сенс цього допису (дайджест нефонемічних явищ мови), але здається, авторові варто більш чітко сформулювати запитання. Наприклад, за якими словами його мають знаходити користувачі за допомогою пошуку по сайту? Окремо від того, чи не варто такі дописи позначати статусом Community Wiki?

Answer (score 2):

## Апостроф

> [§ 6. Апостроф](http://www.pravopys.net/sections/6/)
>
> Роздільність вимови `я` `ю` `є` `ї` та попереднього твердого приголосного позначається апострофом.
>
> Апостроф пишеться перед `я` `ю` `є` `ї`:
>
> 1. Після губних приголосних `б` `п` `в` `м` `ф`: *бʼю, пʼять, пʼє, вʼязи, у здоровʼї, мʼясо, румʼяний, тімʼя, мерефʼянський, Вʼячеслав, Стефʼюк.*
>
> Примітка. Апостроф не пишеться, коли перед губним звуком є приголосний (крім `р`), який належить до кореня: *дзвякнути, мавпячий, свято, тьмяний, цвях*, але: *вербʼя, торфʼяний, червʼяк*. Коли такий приголосний належить до префікса, то апостроф пишеться, як і в тих же словах без префікса: *звʼязок, звʼялити, підвʼязати, розмʼякшити*.
>
> 2. Після `р`: *бурʼян, міжгірʼя, пірʼя, матірʼю, курʼєр, на подвірʼї*.
>
> Примітка. Апостроф не пишеться, коли `ря` `рю` `рє` означають сполучення мʼякого `р` із наступними `а` `у` `е`: *буряк, буряний, крякати, рябий, ряд, крюк, Рєпін.*

Смак в примітках і в базової [фонетики](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0), де `б` `в` `г` `ґ` `ж` `к` `м` `п` `ф` `х` `ч` `ш` (`р`) — суто тверді.

1. У минулому були слова: *[сьвато](http://www.l-ukrainka.name/uk/Folklore/Goncharenko/248.html)*, [*тьманий* чи *тьмʼяний*](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/hrinchenko_slovar_ukrainskoi_movy/%D1%82%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE), [*цьвах*](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D0%B2%D1%8F%D1%85) чи *[цьвак](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/hrinchenko_slovar_ukrainskoi_movy/%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BA)* — подібних слів тоді вистачало, тепер їх надто мало чи дисбалансовані (приклад *тьмяний*). Навіть є для `р`: *[бурак](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/hrinchenko_slovar_ukrainskoi_movy/%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA), [бура](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/hrinchenko_slovar_ukrainskoi_movy/%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0)ний, [кракати](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/hrinchenko_slovar_ukrainskoi_movy/%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8)* чи *[кахкати](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/hrinchenko_slovar_ukrainskoi_movy/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8), [крук](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/hrinchenko_slovar_ukrainskoi_movy/%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA)*, хоча `р` може бути помʼякшеним (приклад *гово**ря**ть*, хоча синонімів до цього слова надто багато: *кажуть, балакають* — але це не суть, бо слів  з `ря` дійсно вистачає).
2. Апостроф відсутний у *мавпячий* чи непопулярність *мавповий*.
3. Багато нових иншомовних слів порушують цього

> [§ 92. Апостроф](http://www.pravopys.net/sections/92/)
>
> 1. Апостроф у словах іншомовного походження та похідних від них пишеться перед `я` `ю` `є` `ї`:
>
>    - після приголосних `б` `п` `в` `м` `ф` `г` `к` `х` `ж` `ч` `ш` `р` *(порівняйте: попередній перелік „суто тверді“, відсутність `ґ` — [правопис 2015](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil3.htm#par92) — **sic**!)*: *бʼєф, компʼютер, пʼєдестал, інтервʼю, премʼєр, торф’яний, кʼянті, мишʼяк, карʼєра; Пʼємонт, Пʼяченца, Ривʼєра, Акʼяб, Іхʼямас; Барб’є, Б’єрнсон, Б’юкенен, Женев’єва, Ф’єзоле, Монтеск’є, Руж’є, Фурʼє;*
>    - після кінцевого приголосного префікса: адʼюнкт, адʼютант, інʼєкція, конʼюнктура.
> 2. Апостроф не пишеться:
>
>    - перед `йо` *(навіть не знаю нащо це)*: *курйоз, серйозний*;
>    - коли `я` `ю` позначають помʼякшення попереднього приголосного перед `а`, `у`: *бязь; бюджет, бюро, пюпітр, мюрид, фюзеляж, кювет, рюкзак, рюш; Барбюс, Бюффон, Вюртемберг, Мюллер, Гюго, Кюв’є, Рюдберг (раптово: ще **Рє**пін — **sic!**)*.

Comment: На яке запитання відповідає ця відповідь?

Answer (score 2):

## Иншомовні слова

> [§ 88. F, Ph, Th](http://www.pravopys.net/sections/88/)
>
> `F` і `ph` передаються літерою `ф`: *фабрика, факт, фартух, фах, фаянс, федеративний, фейлетон, фігура, форма, фуга, футляр, офіційний, реформа; ефемерний, катастрофа, корифей, фараон, фізика, фізіологія, філософія, флегматик, фонетика, фосфор; Флоренція, Франція; Філіппіни, Фінікія; Лонгфелло, Фірдоусі, Фаон.*
>
> `Th` залежно від того, як слово узвичаєне в українській мові, передається то літерою `ф`: *арифметика, ефір, кафедра, логарифм, міф, орфографія, пафос, Федір*, — то літерою `т`: *бібліотека, ортодокс, ортопедія, театр, теорія; Тадей, Теодор.*

Доволі цікаве слово *узвичаєне*, особливо те, що більшість з цього затвердженно у [1960](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/1301/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81-1960-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83). І те, що прибрали правила грецьких літер. А нащо, коли можна *узвичаювати*.

ортодоксія — **ὀρθο**δοξία — **ortho**doxy
ортопедія — **ὀρθο**παιδεία — **ortho**pedics
ор**ф**ографія — **ὀρθο**γραφία — **ortho**graphy

Також було би непогано наголосити, що хоч `ф` і *узвичаїлась*, але не є суто питомою.

***невр**ологія —  **νεῦρ**ολογία — **neur**ology

**нейр**он — **νεῦρ**ον — **neur**on*

Якраз до німецької дійшли.

> [§ 95.Німецький дифтонг EI](http://www.pravopys.net/sections/95/)
>
> 1. Німецький дифтонг `еі`, англійський `ey` та голландський `iy`, `y` передаються через `ей`: *волейбол, гейзер, дрейф, лейтенант, маркшейдер, капельмейстер, штрейкбрехер; Лейпциг, Рейн, Швейцарія; Ван-Дейк, Гейне, Ейнштейн.*
> 2. У власних назвах новішого походження німецький дифтонг `еі` передається через `ай` (`яй`), дифтонг `eu` — через `ой`: *Айзенах, Нойбранденбург, Нортгайм; Вайзенборн, Кайзер, Майнгоф, Нойбауер*.

*капель**мейстер** — kapell**meister**

**майстер** — **meister***

Чомусь прибрали приклад зі наступною голосною, бо це просто показово. Наприклад *F**eue**rbach* — тепер [Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B3_%D0%A4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%94%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%85) гадає: *узвичаєний* московиський *Ф**ейє**рбах (**sic!**)* чи *Ф**оє**рбах*.

Answer (score 0):

## Абетка

Зараз

> ```
> А а,   Б б,   В в,   Г г,   Ґ ґ,   Д д,         Е е,   Є є,  
> Ж ж,   З з,   И и,   І і,   Ї ї,   Й й,         К к,   Л л,  
> М м,   Н н,   О о,   П п,   Р р,   С с,         Т т,   У у,  
> Ф ф,   Х х,   Ц ц,   Ч ч,   Ш ш,   Щ щ,  Ь ь,   Ю ю,   Я я
> ```
>
> **Примітка.** Апостроф (’) в алфавіт не входить і на розміщення слів у словнику не впливає; напр.: бур’ян, буряний стоятимуть поруч.
>
> Сполучення літер ***дж*** і ***дз*** (для позначення зімкнено-щілинних звуків [дж̃], [дз̃]) не входять в алфавіт; отже, такі слова, як *джерело*, *дзвін*, стоятимуть у словнику під літерою *д*.

### Проблеми

Не розглядуватимемо про переходи на якусь [иншу письменість](/q/221/) чи повну зміну положення від [латині](/a/4609/585), лиш те що є.

#### Чинний апостроф та положення *ь*

Мусить входити в чинну абетку, оскільки впливає на стандартну вимову. Порівняйте з [чужомовами](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe#Non-English_use).

[Усталеним положенням](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AC#%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0) *ь* було в кінці абетки <sup>[1892](//zbruc.eu/node/66463), [1928](//r2u.org.ua/node/182)</sup>, що не дивно, оскільки *ь* є скоріш знаком. Але найдивнішим є те, що цю усталеність порушили за часи сучасної незалежності.

#### Афрікат букв *дз* та *дж*, і не зовсім *щ*

Мусять мати окремі літери, як і їхні глухі парні *ц* та *ч*. Бо, на відміну московської, є питомими звуками і унеможлює окремого московського читання, особливо в запозичених словах як *менеджер*, *джинси*, *Джордж*…; також розмежовує читання приростків як *від*.

Для порівняння:

```
Дж Дз
Џ     сербська мова
Џ  Ѕ  македонська i колись кирилична румуньська
Ӂ     „колись“ молдовська (зараз латінка)
```

Чого не мовити про *щ*, котрий не є афрікатом чи окремим звуком — лиш позначає *шч*, як його й позначають більшість словʼяньських мов, коли ж ні, то *шт* (окрім балґарської).

### Йотовані голосні і *й*

Голосні

- ріжне написання: або буквою, або двома як *йо*, *йи*; одне з вирішень є [драгоманівка](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0) за цим питанням, котре є найпростішим з багатьма діями: зменшує кількість букв й знищує чинного апострофу, питання положення *ь* вирішене без переміщень;
- [наближення до московської звучні](/a/2592/585): *ї* не мʼякшить й позначає *йі* та *йи*.

Буква *й* це *и* з [бревісом](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%81), котре перекладається як і позначає *короткий*. Для порівняння, білоруське [ў](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%8E) має одне з значінь *коротке У*. Тобто виходить *коротке И*, що не є дійсним, оскільки це *йот* і *коротке І* (котре є [алофоном](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD) і влаштовує московській). Пропонувалась зміна, котра доречна і зараз, на кириличну [*ј*](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%88_(%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8F)), котру, наприклад, мають сербська та македоньська.