# Чому "лідер", але "лідирувати", "лідирує"? Ріже вухо

Tags: етимологія, запозичені-слова, чергування, словотворення

Чи є якесь правило словотвору, за яким саме таким чином відбувається утворення дієслова від іменника? Чому "е" переходить в "и"?

Чому не *"лідувати"*, *"лідує"* від *"lead?"*

Яким чином можна дослідити процес утворення дієслів з цим запозиченим коренем?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

А там ніщо нікуди не переходить.

Слово ***лідер*** походить з англійської мови, від англійського ***leader***, іменника, утвореного за допомогою суфікса імені діяча ***-er*** від дієслівного кореня ***lead*** «вести», отже, ***leader*** означає «вождь; той, хто веде».

*Лідирувати* – це росіянизм, слово-покруч, утворене від того самого англійського кореня ***lead*** «вести» за допомогою запозиченого з німецької суфікса *-ир-* (нім. *-ier-*) (cf. нім. kontrolieren), який широко вживається в росіянській, а українській геть не властивий (cf. укр. *контролювати*).

Особисто мені слово *лідирувати* здається бридким та огидним, всі слова з суфіксом *-ир-* – росіянізми. Як на мене, то воно взагалі непотрібне, є ж наше чудове слово ***вести***.

Comment: нам терміново потрібний етимолоґічний словник, що його можна буде оновлювати онлайн з перевіркою модераторами, бо це якийсь хаос суцільний.

Answer (score 4):

**Чому лїдирувати?**

1. Тому що московське [*лид**и**ровать*](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x) файне, бо:

   - наголошене перше *и* — не звучить
   - змінене друге *и* на наголошене *е* — буде *лид**ьо**ривать*
   - байдуже на ориґінал та свій стандарт, а анґлїйське *е* бува *и*
   - чи то взагалї з [нїмецької](http://lingvoforum.net/index.php?topic=19383.0) — [*leadieren*](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ger_rus/93388/leadieren)
2. По-инакшому, полонїзм — [*lider**o**wać*](https://sjp.pwn.pl/slowniki/liderowa%C4%87.html), мовили би совєти:

   - Як так, що роблять институти? Сам [не знаю](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/2627/).

---

**Чому не лїдувати?**

1. Тому що ***вчитель*** *вчить* і *вчителює*. Себто *бути лїдером* — *лїдерувати*, а *вести по-лїдерськи* — *лїдувати*.
2. Є слова: [*вести*](http://sum.in.ua/s/vesty), [*водити*](http://sum.in.ua/s/vodyty), [*первувати*](http://sum.in.ua/s/pervuvaty) і так далї.

---

[Бориз Рогоза](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0_%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81_%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) підтверджує мої основнї догадки, ґазета [Хрещатик](http://mova.kreschatic.kiev.ua/235.htm).

> **Лїдирувати чи лїдерувати?**
>
> Дїєслово *лїдирувати*, що часто вживаєтця в текстах на спортивну тематику, утворене за моделлю, яка дуже активна в московській мові: *агитировать, акцентировать, анализировать, анулировать, дебатировать, депонировать, консервировать, конспектировать, контролировать, фиксировать, цементировать*. У своїй структурі такі слова мають пень переважно з латинської чи гелладської мов і наросток *-ир* (нїмецький з походження).
>
> Деякі з них спочатку виступали і в нас з цим наростком (*бравірувати, мусирувати, шокірувати*), але згодом їх витїснили закономірнїші українські варіянти — *бравувати, мусувати, шокувати*.
>
> У сучаснїй лїтературнїй мові зберігаютця дїєслова *компостирувати, репетирувати, курирувати*, вже згадане *лїдирувати*. Щодо перших двох мовознавцї пояснюють це прагненням уникнути надмірної омонїмії: є вже *компостувати* — *перетворювати на добриво* (*компост*) та *репетувати* — *голосно кричати*.
>
> Але багато мовцїв не сприймають лексем з *-ир*, які ріжуть слух. Замість *репетирувати* кажуть *проводити репетицїю*, замість *компостирувати* — таки *компостувати* (в даному разї нема чого боятися звукового збігу з сїльськогосподарським терміном, бо віддаленість двох понять і контекст допомагають уникнути непорозуміння) чи *пробивати квитки*, замість *курирувати* — *опікуватися, наглядати*.
>   Вислови з *лїдирувати* можна замінити синонїмічними *вести перед, бути попереду, бути лідером* тощо. Або вживати дїєслова *лїдерувати, лїдерує*. Адже твірним словом є іменник *лїдер*.

---

Цьому також частково підтверджує навіть сучасний (2015 наразї) правопис:

> [**§ 24. Дієслівні суфікси**](http://www.pravopys.net/sections/24/)
>
> 3. Дієслова іншомовного походження, що мають у мові-джерелі суфікс **-ір-**, в українській мові втрачають цей суфікс у всіх формах: *загітува́ти — загіто́ваний, зареєструва́ти — зареєстро́ваний, інформува́ти — інформо́ваний, сконструюва́ти — сконструйо́ваний*. Але в окремих словах для усунення небажаної омонімії суфікс **-ір-** (після **д**, **т**, **з**, **с**, **ц**, **ж**, **ч**, **ш**, **р** — **-ир-**) зберігається: *букси́рувати* (бо є *буксува́ти*), *пари́рувати* (бо є парува́ти), *полірува́ти* (бо є *полюва́ти*), *репети́рувати* (бо є *репетува́ти*) тощо.
>       
>      Суфікс **-ір-** (**-ир-**) уживається також у поодиноких дієсловах типу *коти́рувати, лаві́рувати, марширува́ти, пікі́рувати, трети́рувати*.

До слова *лїдувати* наче немає омонїмії. Схоже, тут воно за параметром *поодиноких дієсловах*, типу [*узвичаїлись*](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/2627/2629#2629).

Comment: Чому у своїй відповіді Ви не використовуєте діючий правопис? До чого тут _л**ї**дирувати_, _**и**нститути_, _Д**ї**єслово_ і т.д? Поясніть, будь ласка.

Comment: якого року цей правопис? чому Ви не використовуєте сучасний?

Comment: Це нормально, мати власну позицію, в тому числі й щодо правопису. Я навчений в сучасній школі теперішньому правопису, але цілком поділяю думку, що буква "Ї" повинна пом'якшувати попередній звук подібно до букв "я", "ю", "є", тоді як буква "і" повинна бути твердою, подібно до звуку, який чуємо в англійському слові "теа".

Comment: @ЮрійГладьо якщо кожен тут буде мати свою власну позицію щодо правопису і писати як йому заманеться, яким чином цей сайт допоможе людям покращити свої знання української мови? Тим більше, що ukrainian.stackexchange.com був створений не тільки для тих, для кого українська мова є рідною.

Comment: @Idolon, хоча особисто я також є прихильником класичного правопису, пропоную ваш edit suggestion скасувати, а натомість підняти дискусію у [meta].